# Should I set a limit for the uploading file size in jfrog through UI?

Tags: file-upload, artifactory

As a DevOps admin, I want to know if we should set up a limit for uploading a file to the artifactory through UI.
If yes, what is the recommended size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI upload limit by default is 100MB for the Artifactory. The default limit is the optimal setting to prevent browser session timeouts.

If you want to set the limit according to your requirement you can go to Admin -> Artifactory -> General -> Setting and change "File Upload In UI Max Size"

In general, the recommended way to deploy large files is via REST API, where a deploy query might look something like this:

```
curl -X PUT -u myUser:myPassword -T test.txt "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/test/test.txt"
```

More Info: In case of UI failures you can use this [Knowledge Base article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-should-i-do-if-an-upload-through-the-ui-fails/) in order to find and resolve the issue.